# El tempura es un plato japonés que se dice... ¿Influenciado por los portugueses? ¿Haber sido influenciado?

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, aspecto-gramatical

> El tempura es un plato japonés que se dice *influenciado* por los portugueses que residían en Japón en el pasado.

¿Esta oración está correcta? O será:

> El tempura es un plato japonés que se dice *haber sido influenciado* por los portugueses que residían en Japón.

Comment: O ,  "..que se dice fue influenciado..."

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo diría así:

> “El tempura es un plato japonés **que se dice fue influenciado** por los portugueses que residían en Japón en el pasado.”

o bien, un poco más complejo pero también más claro:

> “El tempura es un plato japonés **del que se dice que fue influenciado** por los portugueses que residían en Japón en el pasado.”

(También vale “...**del cual** se dice...”.) Me gusta más la segunda alternativa porque, aunque es más larga, respeta más las reglas comunes de la subordinación en español. La primera alternativa es más propia del registro literario y utiliza una forma de subordinación excepcional.